# Is GoogleFit App mandatory installed on device for getting Automatically Tracked steps and activity data?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am aware about the [GoogleFit Faq](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq) and it is answered there

> **Do I need to install the Google Fit app to use the APIs?** 
> No, you don't need to install the Google Fit app to use the APIs or the Fit platform.

But I am seeing cases where **GoogleFit Android SDK API** is **giving 0 steps, 0 activities**. When **GoogleFit app is installed and enabled Automatic Tracking**, it starts giving data.

So question is:

1. Is **automatic tracking enabled** for the **user or the device by default**, without installing Google Fit App?
2. Is the settings **per device or per user** ?
3. We are seeing **automatic tracking is by default disabled on GoogleFit App "Get started" screen**. If it is not enabled, data won't come (unless user has multiple devices where tracking is enabled). Which means users have to enable it to sync data third party app, which means they need to install GoogleFit app to turn it on. So, question is again: 
   **Does a user need to install the Google Fit app to sync activity data?**
4. Is there any way **(Any API) developers can find whether Auto Tracking is disabled or not**, with which we can guide/ask users to turn it on (To avoid users raising issues/support tickets) ?
5. Is there **any way or any API where developers can turn on Automatic Tracking**  (of-course with user consent) without installing GoogleFit App?

Answer (score 0):

Your app can use the Google Fit Android APIs to [record data](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record).

Comment: Hi, I am aware of tracking data into GoogleFIt. My question is not about fetching Automatic Activity Track data from GoogleFit without installing GoogleFit app and is automatic tracking enabled by default.